# attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference android

Tags: android

```
  04-05 04:02:50.197 11202-11202/com.Salman.apple.flashlight E/FlashLight: failed to open Camera
04-05 04:02:52.041 11202-11564/com.Salman.apple.flashlight E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-05 04:02:58.974 11202-11202/com.Salman.apple.flashlight E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.Salman.apple.flashlight, PID: 11202
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.startPreview()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.Salman.apple.flashlight.MainActivity$FlashOnOffListener.onClick(MainActivity.java:115)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please ask clear questions to get helpful answers

Comment: Please paste relevant code to support your question.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera$Parameters.setFlashMode(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.. Getting this error (Sorry for redundant question i am new here)

Answer (score 0):

```js
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private TextView batterylevel;
        private Camera camera;
        private Camera.Parameters parameters;
        private ImageButton btn_power;
        boolean isFlashLightOn = false;
        MediaPlayer mp;
        Context context;
        private AdView mAdView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                        .build();
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

                btn_power = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_power);
                btn_power.setOnClickListener(new FlashOnOffListener());

                batterylevel = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batterylevel);
                Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Advantage Demi Oblique.ttf");
                batterylevel.setTypeface(face);
                getbatterypercentage();

                       /* if (isFlashSupported()){

                                camera = Camera.open();
                                parameters = camera.getParameters();
                        }
                        else {
                                showNoFlashAlert();
                        }*/

                        try{

                                onDestroy();

                                if(isFlashSupported()){
                                        camera = camera.open();
                                        parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                }
                                else {
                                        showNoFlashAlert();
                                }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                                Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
                if (camera != null) {

                        camera.stopPreview();
                        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                        camera.release();
                        camera.setParameters(parameters);
                        camera = null;
                }
                super.onDestroy();
        }

        private class FlashOnOffListener implements View.OnClickListener{

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(isFlashLightOn){
                                btn_power.setImageResource(R.drawable.flashlight_button_off);
                                parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                camera.stopPreview();
                                isFlashLightOn = false;
                                playSound();
                        }else{
                                btn_power.setImageResource(R.drawable.flashlight_button_on);
                                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                camera.startPreview();
                                isFlashLightOn = true;
                                playSound();
                        }

                }

        }

        private void showNoFlashAlert() {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setMessage("Your device hardware does not support flashlight!")
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Error")
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        finish();
                                }
                        }).show();
        }

        private boolean isFlashSupported() {
                PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
        }



     
        
        ilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
                registerReceiver(batteryLevelReciever, batteryLevelFilter);
        }


        //    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                return true;
        }

        

}
```

Comment: Please, edit your question and paste this code there.